# Hibernate manyToMany only persist

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, persistence, cascade

I want to create a manyToMany-Relation in Hibernate with only "persist" as cascade type.

My meal class looks like this:

```
public class Meal {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name="meal_ingredient_relation",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="meal_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id")})
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

And my ingredient class looks like this:

```
public class Ingredient {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<Meal> meals = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

If I want to create some meals with some ingredients

```
SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sf.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Ingredient ingredient1 = new Ingredient("in1");
Ingredient ingredient2 = new Ingredient("in2");

Meal meal1 = new Meal("meal1", 100);
Meal meal2 = new Meal("meal2", 200);

meal1.getIngredients().add(ingredient1);
meal1.getIngredients().add(ingredient2);
meal2.getIngredients().add(ingredient1);

session.save(meal1);
session.save(meal2);
```

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: hibernate.entities.Ingredient
```

Comment: You might want to save the two Ingredient first before you save the meal.

Comment: Doesn't hibernate do this for me? I thought the cascade type "persist" is there to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an annotation to your `setIngredients` in the `Meal` class:

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
```

Or if you are using XML mapping:

`<set name="ingredients" cascade="save-update, delete" ...`

obviously use `DELETE` only if needed.

Comment: There is no javax.persistence.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE. Do I need to import another package?

Comment: Uhm, what [version of Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html#SAVE_UPDATE) are you using? The package is `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType` BTW

Comment: I am using 4.2.2. But I found the package: org.hibernate.annotations. This actually worked, thanks! :)